# Game Theory: One player finding the best-response function

Tags: game-theory

Let's say two players are playing a game to maximize an objective $O$.

The first player learns the best-response function of the second player (how second player move will affect the objective), and the second player plays by observing the best-response function from the first player.

Is there a name for these kinds of strategy? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are describing a game where the first player makes a move by *correctly anticipating* what the second player will respond to that move, then you can call such reasoning [**backward induction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_induction).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was more looking for two agent game, where the first agent just learns the best-response function and the other follows the best-response function learnt by the first agent. I was suspecting it is called Stackelberg competition.

Comment: @JLB Stackelberg competiton is the name of a game in the context of industrial organization. Backward induction is the method to solve such games.

Comment: Thanks! I should look into that :)